# I get some error when i insert this particular USB disk in , dosent give any error in other OS

Tags: usb, mount

**Says unable to mount at heading**

`` Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/user/HRM_CCSA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV5: Command-line `mount -t "udf" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/user/HRM_CCSA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV5"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
           missing codepage or helper program, or other error ``

**I get this error everytime I insert this particular USB disk. No other operating system gives me this error. I have tried formatting through software and also through other operating systems.**

This issue has been there since I tried to create a windows 8 bootstick through ubuntu (for obvious reasons).

I followed these methods:

- 1st [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)
- And when that did not work I followed another method (not able to find that answer right now) which used Gparted to do the trick. None worked for me, as the pendrives were not detected at boot.

**So how do I fix this error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the error!

It says what's wrong:

> exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Wrong FS type. The drive has a bad/unreadable filesystem. It's probably formatted NTFS, so try running

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

to get a native NTFS driver, or use gparted to format the drive with a more compatible FS, like FAT32.

Comment: hey 
I tried running that code , its said it was already installed, I already tried formatting to FAT32 dosent work.

Comment: Ah so it seems the drive has a bad/invalid file system. Back up whatever is important on it and format it with a FAT32 file system

Comment: I did that through Gparted but i found 3-4 partitions within itself which i managed to clean up and make 1 FAT32 partition, but one of those partitions refuses to be removed, it says successfully done but it comes back again.This time when i insert the disk there are 4 variations of the said error but there is a 14GB partition that has been succesfully mounted out of the 16GB.

Comment: guess that's the most i can ask for , Thank you for your help , Atleast i ahve 14GB now instead of a brick XD thanks again.

Comment: @ripc0rd 14.91 GiB = 16 GB. Computers count differently than humans ;)

Comment: haha funny how stuff happens